# How do you create multiple pages in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a login page and the main page. After login, I have

```
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // go to the next page
        SDM_Mailer page = new SDM_Mailer();
        RootPanel.get().remove(0);
        RootPanel.get().add(page);
    }
```

However RootPanel does not accept an EntryPoint object! add() only accepts a Widget! Ok, so I extend Widget

> public class SDM_Mailer extends Widget implements EntryPoint {

But now when I try to edit SDM_Mailer in the GWT Designer, it gives this error:

[image: Imgur]

So exactly how do you create multiple pages, that are not all in the same giant class file or using tab? I know I've done this before but don't remember and with an older version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
package com.example.client;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.History;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Controller implements EntryPoint {
    private static Controller instance;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName());

    // I have a feeling GWT does not respect private constructors, or else it uses some other voodoo.
    private Controller(){}

    public static Controller getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new Controller();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        String token = History.getToken();
        log.info("****************************** token:"+token);
        History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                navigate(event.getValue());
            } // onValueChange
        });
        if (token == null || token.length() == 0) History.newItem(Login.TOKEN); // no token
        else navigate(token); // restore app state
    }

    private static void navigate(String token) {
        RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("gwtApp");
        if (rootPanel.getWidgetCount() > 0) rootPanel.remove(0); // clear the page

        if (Login.TOKEN.equals(token)) {
            Login page = Login.getInstance();
            page.onModuleLoad();
        } else if (MainApp.TOKEN.equals(token)) {
            MainApp page = MainApp.getInstance();
            page.onModuleLoad(); // display the page
//          page.setAuthenticated(true);
//          page.setUsername(email);
        }

    }

} // Controller
```

In your *.gwt.xml file:

```
<entry-point class='com.example.client.Controller' />
```

Now when you want to go to a new page:

```
History.newItem(Login.TOKEN);
```

This seems quite familiar and is probably what I came up with a few years ago.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It's not the way GWT is suppose to be used. There should only be one `EntryPoint`. Ypu should really use MVP.

Comment: It's exactly how GWT is supposed to be used. History is in the docs. Otherwise the Google plugin would provide a drop down menu to 'Create New GWT Page' and it would automatically add all the boiler plate and it would be editable in GWT Designer and there would be a simple multi-page example in the Getting Started guide. Seeing as how none of that exists, Google wants you to make your own controller and navigation framework. It's very unlike Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt **Activities and Places**.

As mentioned to the official [gwt project site](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html):

> The Activities and Places framework allows you to create bookmarkable URLs within your application, thus allowing the browser's back button and bookmarks to work as users expect.

**Activity**

> An activity simply represents something the user is doing. An Activity contains no Widgets or UI code.

**Place**

> A place is a Java object representing a particular state of the UI. A Place can be converted to and from a URL history token

Source: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

Answer (score 0):

You usually only have one `EntryPoint` from there you add different widgets (which can represent your different pages) and manage them.

A very simple way to do this is for a small app can be to use `.setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)` on different widgets that represent pages, but this is not a good method in the long run.

You could also have a container widget in which you add whatever widget you want to display and then when you want to put a new widget in it you clear it.

```
container.clear();
container.add(widget)
```

The suggestions above are ok for small apps but aren't great when your app has a lot of pages (views). A popular way to manage pages (views) is to use [MVP Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html). It's a lot of overhead but is scalable and works well.

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you thinkg that hidden/visible solution is secure? For instance I can imagine that someone without login, just simply changes the html property and can access the authorized version of the page. What is your opinion?

Comment: It depends how you give access to the widgets. If it's purely by URL then it could be a security issue. But all you need to do is check the permissions before you set the view. It's basically the same issue with `.clear()`/`.add()` or with MVP Activities and Places. You need to check the permissions before you make any view visible.

Comment: @fascynacja It's definitely not secure, but then your whole application is downloaded to begin with, and if the user was determined, could decompile all the Javascript. Always verify authentication and credentials on the server-side for every action. This answer doesn't really address separating multiple pages and editing them in the designer in separate files. You can't just use Widget classes because the designer won't load Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Widget doesn't magically make something representable in HTML. Widgets provide graphical representations of something in HTML, that is, a way to render themselves into HTML, this is ussualy achieved by implementing [UIBinders](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html). I strongly suggest you take the MVP approach and use Activities, Places and Views. check the [official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) on how to do it, it's simpler than you may think.

If you are working with Eclipse, [the GWT plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started) does most of the boilerplate. You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGJC_i7Dw6c) on how to use it.